# Android studio scratched off text

Tags: android, android-studio

My Android Studio is scratching off text in the menu items, and it's been hard to deal with. I've tried reinstalling, but it hasn't been helping. I have a linked image, so you guys have a clear picture of it. Any ideas?

[image: Scratched-off text in Android Studio]

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This might help:  IntelliJ can have rendering issues with high dpi.

https://superuser.com/questions/614960/how-to-fix-font-anti-aliasing-in-intellij-idea-when-using-high-dpi

Answer (score 0):

You can try going to `Settings` (Ctrl + alt + s)

-> Appearance and Behavior ->  Appearance -> Ui options

-> Override default fonts (change font and / or size)

Maybe it will work.